# How to retrieve all cells based on a criteria using a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to retrieve all data based on a criteria,  for instance, given this cells:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
a 4 
a 5
```

I would like to search for all values with "a" than i would like to retrieve:

```
a 1
a 4
a 5
```

Is that possible using formulas??

I need it in order to easily create charts. for instance, type a letter in a cell, an them a chart will be created using the data based on the letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your columns are A and B, you can use this array formula:

If in `E1`, you have "a", in `F1`, you can use: `=INDEX($B$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$5)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROWS($A$1:A1)))`

Enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> and drag down.  This will update as the values in column `A` change as well.

[image]

Finally, to hide the errors just use `IFERROR()`: `=IFERROR([formula],"")`.

And just to note, if you don't necessarily need a formula, you could just put a Filter on the data, and filter out all "non-a" values.

Comment: FYI, one thing I have learned is that when using small like you do to return the row number we can use a full column in the INDEX part and remove the need of the `-ROW($A$1)+1` without detriment to the speed: `=INDEX($B:$B,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROWS($A$1:A1)))`  You could also use `ROW(1:1)` in place of `ROWS($A$1:A1)` for less typing but that is personal choice.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Oh, nice!! Thanks for that tip, I'll definitely make note.